# how to Install IBM MobileFirst as a cluster

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am planning to use MFP V8 and would like some advise on how to configure it as a cluster . Basically, I have load balancer and a MySQL Node . I would like to have 2 additional node with MFP V8.

Application server = tomcat

1:How can I set it up as a  cluster

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned if you will be installing MFP v8 on WAS ND or Liberty or Tomcat.Since you mention a cluster I am assuming this is WAS ND or Liberty Farm collective.

Good amount of the steps are the same, with only minor changes to the configuration you select.

Essentially the steps are:

- Running IBM Installation Manager
  IBM Installation Manager installs the IBM MobileFirst Platform Server files and tools on your computer.
- Setting up databases
  Set up the database to be used by MobileFirst Server components.
- Choosing your topologies and network flows
  Topics about possible server topologies for MobileFirst Server components and the network flows.
- Installing MobileFirst Server to an application server

More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_install_mfp_server_production.html).

To install MFP you can chose either :

- [Server Configuration Tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_install_mfp_server_components_sct.html) (SCT)

  or
- [Ant scripts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_install_mfp_server_components_ant.html)

To set it up as a cluster, you first configure the WAS ND Cluster or Liberty Collective and then chose that as your deployment option using SCT or Ant scripts.

You will find most of the detailed installation steps [here](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/prod-env/).